# VB.NET Windows Service TimeOut

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a WindowsService built with VB.NET that gets a TimeOut on 30000 milliseconds on some servers only. 
When it happens, the only entry I find about it on the Event manager is the exception stating it had been taking more than 30000 milliseconds to start and it failed.

My OnStart tries to be quick and from it I only fire a timer that will log the time it started and deal with all tasks that have to be performed. Bellow is the code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    '-- request additional time to see if we get rid of timeout on service
    Me.RequestAdditionalTime(120000)

    '-- we created a timer to be triggered on OnStart so the Service will start quickly and then run the rest
    '   of the starting code in order not to time out in some servers that take longer to start SQL Server
    OnStartTimer.Interval = 10000
    OnStartTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

As we can see, I have even tried to increase the time needed using RequestAdditionalTime, but it didn't seem to help. The OnStart will do nothing but enable a Timer and get out. This makes me wonder if the process even got to OnStart at all during those 30 seconds.

I have many Timers (16) instantiated through the .Designer.vb, they each will take care of different tasks and they are all created with Enable = False, so I will only start them outside the OnStart and nothing else is done, that is all about it.

Any ideas of what else I could try to at least find out what makes the Service to take so long to start?

Comment: Well, that can't be it.  Consider your Main() method.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no Main() method. The OnStart will start a Timer and exit. This should tell the OS the timer is running, right?

Comment: Researching a bit further, I have just realized that my ServiceProcessInstaller is set to run under LocalSystem account. Could this prevent the service to start depending on the server policy?

Comment: Sorry, on the answer to Hans Passant, I meant that once OnStart exit, it should tell the OS the Service is then running.

Comment: Another possible issue, my assembly is Authenticode signed and this apparently generates a runtime check that could require some time on slow internet environments.

Comment: I guess no one else has any ideas on this...